# Jenkins DSL using the Build Blocker Plugin plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I am writing a Jenkins DSL script (groovy) that will create a Jenkins Job.  One of the options I would like the job to have enabled is the box that reads "Block build if certain jobs are running"

I tried to use the "blockOn" code that I found here:
https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/freeStyleJob-blockOn

But when I run my DSL script the job gets created and does NOT have the "Block build if certain jobs are running" box checked

Below is the entire DSL script that gets executed:

```
job('Testing-DSL') {
  blockOn(['2.Dummy_job', '1 .Dummy_job']) {
    blockLevel('GLOBAL')
    scanQueueFor('ALL')
} //closing blockOn section

      description('''\
This is just a template job that I use to reference how groovy code should look<br>
 ''')

logRotator(-1, 30, -1, -1)

parameters {
    choiceParam('CHOICE1', ['choice_option1', 'option2'], 'Some description for this param')
    stringParam('STRING1', 'Default_Value_string1', 'Some description for this option')

} //closing parameters section

    steps {
    shell('''\
echo $CHOICE1
echo $STRING1
''')

} //closing steps section
} //closing job section
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is working for me, the "Block build if certain jobs are running" box is checked.

You may need to restart Jenkins before using Job DSL if you installed some plugins. See also https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#why-isnt-my-generated-job-like-i-was-expecting-there-was-no-error-when-the-seed-job-ran.

Comment: How embarrassing.  Good call.  Restarted Jenkins (I had just installed the plugin without a restart)